# Fastest way to move data between GoGrid and Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to move 100+ Gigs of data from GoGrid to Amazon EC2 as a one-off migration task.

What's the best/fastest way for doing that you can recommend?

Servers on both ends are Windows if that helps in anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Does GoGrid offer a service that will copy your data to a USB drive and ship it to you?

If so then you can ship the drive to Amazon, they will mount it and copy the data into your S3 account ready for use. This also avoids the traffic charges for the file transfer.

More information on Amazon's service can be found at http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

Comment: I'm afraid not. Also I think that would be faster if we had terabytes of data, 100+ gigs might be still faster to copy. Although it will have the charges attached.